# jQuery move a div after another div inside a div using insertAfter

Tags: jquery

I'm failing at the following since 2 hours. I'm trying to move the `div id="msg"` after the `div class="meta anchor"` when `<i class="icon-delete delete"></i>` is clicked. The whole thing has me in knots, because of the way it's structured.

I've marked where the div id="msg" should move to. Can you pls help? My failed efforts are below.

```
    <div class="reQ">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="links"> 
                    <div class="icons"><i class="icon-delete delete"></i></div>
                </div>

                <div class="meta anchor">
                    Content
                </div>
                !-- div id="msg" goes here --!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="msg">Div with Message</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.delete').live('click', function() {

    var self = $(this);
    // $('#msg').insertAfter(self.parent()).show();
    // self.parent().after('.msg');

    self.parents('.reQ').$('#msg').insertAfter('.anchor').show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhR36/)

**Edit**
The html part repeats several times on the page. It holds posts. I need the `msg` to go under only the post where the icon was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    var anchor = $(this).closest('.post').find('.anchor');
    $('#msg').insertAfter(anchor).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhR36/4/

Also you are using jquery 1.7 so you should change `live` to `.on`

Here is the doc on insertAfter http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: That works, but what I forgot to mention was that the html part I posted repeats itself sever times on the page. It holds posts. So I need the div i'm trying to move right under `.anchor` in the post where the icon was clicked. Hence, my use of `this` etc.

Comment: @Norman updated, I am unsure if you want to move the msg from post to post or have the message stay under each post.

Comment: `#msg` will have to move from post to post. So if I click the icon in post 1, it'll have to move there, if I click it in post 3 it'll have to move there. In the end (in production), it will contain a form that I'll use to send admin messages if a post needs correction or any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**Js**

```
$(".icon-delete").click(function() {
    $("#msg").insertAfter(".meta");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but functions:

```
$( ".meta" ).click(function() {
    $( "#msg" ).insertAfter( $( ".meta" ));
    $( "#msg" ).removeAttr( "id" );
});
```